# Get request with Python requests returning different page than seen in browser

Tags: python, google-chrome, http, python-requests

I have been trying to do a get request on a YouTube video page in order to read simple information off of the page. I have done this many times before, and generally it is quite easy to reverse engineer a get request with the help of Google Chrome's developer tools.

To demonstrate, here is a screen shot of the request I get when I reload a YouTube video in a fresh incognito window (to prevent cookies from being sent) as seen from the developer menu:
[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaY40.png)

Every time I close the window and reload the page I recieve nearly identical  HTML (apart from authorization keys and the like), the bottom of which can seen here: [another chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROdtp.png)

First I tried recreating this request using a header-less get with Requests in Python:

```
import requests

sesh = requests.Session()
print sesh.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eA8IVrQWn8").content
```

this returns a different page which still contains some of the data present on the page I get from chrome but not nearly all of it. Next I tried including all the headers I saw in the chrome request using the following code:

```
import requests

sesh = requests.Session()
headers = {
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
                "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"}

print sesh.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eA8IVrQWn8", headers = headers).content
```

However this very strangely returns a seemingly random quick paragraph of unicode characters in varying lengths, sometimes around 10 characters long, sometimes closer to 50. I couldn't think of any other ways to make this closer to the request I was seeing from chrome. I tried fiddling with this for a couple of hours doing things like running the request multiple times in the same session and messing with the headers a bit, but to no avail.

FInally out of desperation I tried dropping everything except the user agent, using the following code:

```
import requests

sesh = requests.Session()
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"}
print sesh.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eA8IVrQWn8", headers = headers).content
```

And this got me the page I wanted.

However I am left unsatisfied with the knowledge that somehow replicating the Get I was seeing in chrome didn't work. What am I missing from my second attempt?

Comment: Perhaps you should describe more specifically what the difference between the results of the two requests are.

Comment: As the pages are quite long it's difficult to go into details, but if you look at this comparison dump between the two it's quite easy to see the two pages are completely different: (https://www.diffchecker.com/Ink2lNJM). I downloaded them both to compare by viewing the HTML files in a browser, the page I get from my header-less python program is a very basic html version of the youtube page, while the page I get from chrome doesn't even load, I assume because of some java script that refuses to display the page until other sections are loaded or some similar function.

Comment: Just use the same headers except the 'accept encoding' header since with that you're claiming to accept compression schemes requests doesn't support. You can verify this with the 'copy as CURL' option and skipping the compression.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In the future I should make sure to be aware of what I'm actually saying with the headers.